# Detect if css position overflow is working?

Tags: css, ios, overflow

As iOS5 beta has fixed css property overflow: scroll and overflow: auto, I’d like to target the older iOS versions with Javascript.

Is there a way to check with JS if the property is actually working or not? Trying to get the style property does alert the correct value in both Mobile Safaris, but in the current version it requires a two-finger scrolling to work.

Comment: You said the correct value is reported in both versions. What is the issue?

Comment: It reports either auto or scroll yes, but it doesn’t actually work in Mobile Safari, i.e. I cannot check if it’s actually working or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to check if the scroll property is working but you could check the [`user-agent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html) to determine which version of iOS they're running (3.2 in the following example):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10
```

Comment: Yep, I’m keeping the OS check as the last resort, as I’d have check for multiple iOS versions etc. Would be nice if I could check for feature.

Comment: I've heard of, but never used, the iScroll 4 library to fix broken scrolling in iOS.  Is it something you've tried out? http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Comment: Thanks Pat, I’ll check it out. I’m not going to use the iScroll as is, but maybe I can find something from there to help my situation.